# Can a matrix that is not diagonally dominant be solved by Gauss-Siedel iteration?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm working on the following problem:
[image]

Here's what I've done so far:
$$-2i_1+4i_2+i_3+0i_4=0$$
$$-i_1+0i_2+i_3+6i_4=-14$$
$$5i_1-2i_2-i_3+i_4=6$$
$$i_1+2i_2+6i_3-i_4=6$$
It can be seen that, when put in matrix form, the entire matrix isn't diagonally dominant.
So my question here is, can I still solve this matrix or do I have to reduce down to the echelon form? Help!

Comment: I do that by doing row reduction? Or using eigen vectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Rearrange the equations so they are in diagonally dominant form before applying the Gauss-Seidel (G-S) Algorithm as shown in these [*notes*](http://www.iiserpune.ac.in/~pgoel/GaussSeidel.pdf).

After doing this, the system to solve using G-S is

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 5 & -2 & -1 & 1 \\
 -2 & 4 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 2 & 6 & -1 \\
 -1 & 0 & 1 & 6 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 i_1 \\
 i_2 \\
 i_3 \\
 i_4 \\
\end{array}
\right)\text{ = }\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 6 \\
 0 \\
 6 \\
 -14 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Performing the algorithm with a starting point of $I_0 = (0,0,0,0)^T$, after eleven iterations, it converges to the correct result of

$$i_1 = 2, i_2 = 1, i_3 = 0, i_4 = -2$$

Of course, they only want you to perform five iterations.